# Добавление анимации печатания текста Telegram-боту

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

Написал первого Telegram-бота на java при помощи библиотеки TelegramBotsApi. Реализовал отправку сообщений, всё в целом работает.

Однако, когда текст ответа бота слишком длинный, то отправка этого сообщения занимает некоторое время.

Хотелось бы реализовать появление анимации пишущего карандаша, чтобы пользователь видел, что бот не завис, а пишет.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть метод [sendChatAction](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendchataction) в Telegram Bot API.

Чтобы отправить запрос с помощью библиотеки [TelegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots), сформируйте объект [`SendChatAction`](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/master/telegrambots-meta/src/main/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/methods/send/SendChatAction.java), передайте ему `chatId` и `action`:

```java
SendChatAction method = new SendChatAction();
method.setChatId(chatId);
method.setAction(action);
execute(method);
```

В качестве [`action`](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/master/telegrambots-meta/src/main/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/methods/ActionType.java) передайте одну из следующих констант:

```
ActionType.TYPING
ActionType.RECORDVIDEO
ActionType.RECORDVIDEONOTE
ActionType.RECORDVOICE
ActionType.UPLOADPHOTO
ActionType.UPLOADVIDEO
ActionType.UPLOADVIDEONOTE
ActionType.UPLOADVOICE
ActionType.UPLOADDOCUMENT
ActionType.FINDLOCATION
```

Передавайте константу в зависимости от типа контента, который вы передаете. Анимация для разного типа контента будет разная.

Согласно документации, анимация будет отображаться 5 секунд или меньше (до того момента, пока вы не отправите пользователю новое сообщение).